# Why does method rowControllerAtIndex of WKInterfaceTable return nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

When I run the code below, the method `rowControllerAtIndex` of `WKInterfaceTable` returns nil.

```
[self.outletTable setNumberOfRows:numberOfCategoriesToShow withRowType:@"rowTypeLabel"];
RowControllerTypeLabel *theRow = [self.outletTable rowControllerAtIndex:rowInTable];
```

**What I've checked:**

1. I have made the connection between the row in the storyboard and the corresponding property in the interface of `RowControllerTypeLabel`.
2. I have set the field `Custom Class` of my label to my custom class `RowControllerTypeLabel`.
3. I have also made the connection between the table in the storyboard and the corresponding property in the interface of my interface controller.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I forgot to set the row controller's identifier `rowTypeLabel` in the Attributes inspector.

I hope that this post will help others to find the problem in a shorter time than I needed.

Comment: If you have your row controller, but your outlets is nil -> Beware of using "reserved" names in your row controller, for example label with name `title` will bring you a lot of pain. It's not very straightforward that it's forbidden, since you create `NSObject` subclass.

Comment: If you are having trouble finding the Identifier field, like I was, make sure you have the actual Row Controller selected and not the Group, by selecting it from the Document Outline pane on the left.

Answer (score 6):

For me - while the module was spelt out correctly - from copying and pasting of scenes / renaming classes - something went a miss and it was temporarily disconnected.  I had to reselect the drop down for it to kick in.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To solve you have to set the row controller's identifier in the Attributes Inspector: 
[image]